# Ext JS: Event beforeload not not called in TreeStore

Tags: events, extjs, onload, extjs6

I defined a simple TreeStore like below:

```
Ext.define('myApp.myStores.procoTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    constructor: function (config) {
        var store = this;

        this.callParent(arguments);

        store.on({
            scope: store,
            beforeload: this.foo
        });
    },
    foo: function () {
        colsole.log('foo called');
    }
    //listeners: {
    //  beforeload: function (store, operation) {
    //      colsole.log('beforeload called');
    //  }
    //}
});
```

But when I create the `TreeStore` the function `foo` is not called. If I remove the remarks before the listeners the event `beforeload` is called. I have a similar routine for the standard datastore which operates fine. Any suggestion why `foo` is not called?

Answer (score 0):

Well, while you can load a tree store, most of the activity is around node expansion. With a regular store, if you bind it to a grid, it will load the store triggering `beforeload`. With a tree store, if you bind it to a tree panel, you'll expand the root node instead - which is a different set of events (see [`nodebeforeexpand`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#event-nodebeforeexpand))

Comment: I understand that the panel initiates the load of the store and before it starts loading the beforeload event should be triggerd as documented in the Ext.data.ProxyStore class.
In the example however the beforeload-event is handled right when it is part of the listeners, but not when I add it my self (store.on...)